# Installing homebrew packages during Docker build

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile, homebrew

I am trying to install setup a docker image and want certain Homebrew packages pre-installed when I run the container. I am able to build it just fine and version statements are working as expected but when I run the installed packages are missing. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) \
&& brew --version \
&& brew tap aws/tap && brew install aws-sam-cli \
&& sam --version
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the PATH environment variable in the Dockerfile with:

```
ENV PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:~/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH
```

Here is a complete working Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl binutils clang make
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) \
&& brew --version \
&& brew tap aws/tap && brew install aws-sam-cli \
&& sam --version
ENV PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:~/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH
```