# Installing brew package during Docker build not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, homebrew

I am trying to install arduino-cli (a homebrew package) during the docker build, with the following dockerfile.

The docker image seems to build correctly, but when run on my web server, I am getting the following output in my logs.

Note that this problem seems to be similar to [Installing homebrew packages during Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739378/installing-homebrew-packages-during-docker-build), but the accepted answer doesn't seem to help me.

Does this seem to indicate that arduino-cli was not installed correctly, or just that the path hasn't been linked correctly?

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arduino-cli': 'arduino-cli'
```

```sh
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl binutils clang make
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) \
&& brew --version \
&& brew install arduino-cli \
&& arduino-cli version
ENV PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:~/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src

RUN pip install gunicorn django psycopg2-binary whitenoise

COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src

EXPOSE 8000

COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/
    
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the $PATH problem. The reason why the mentioned answer did not work for you is that you are trying to use `arduino-cli` when $PATH *is not yet changed*. This should make it work:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew \
&& mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& ln -s ../Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin \
&& eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) \
&& brew --version \
&& brew install arduino-cli

# first change PATH
ENV PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:~/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH

# then run
RUN arduino-cli version

# not vice-versa
```

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like madness but might I suggest using a [multi stage dockerfile][1] for this. This would eliminate cruft on your container and reduce security access points.

```
FROM homebrew/brew:latest AS brew
RUN brew update
RUN brew install arduino-cli

# RUN brew list ardunio-cli
FROM python:3.6
COPY --from=brew /usr/local/Cellar /user/local

ENV PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:~/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src

RUN pip install gunicorn django psycopg2-binary whitenoise

COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src

EXPOSE 8000

COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/
    
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
```

There may be some addtional symbolic lings to make to get the brew files working but your end container will be much more slim and safe to use.